# Enable GeoLocation On Webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Good Evening. I'm on making Tracking Application on Android using Webview. i got problem because the system all works well beside the location.

in manifest i got this permission settings already

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

and in mainactivity.java i got this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.primaniagatracking.com/slogin.php");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}}
```

i don't know what missing to make it works may be by always appearing ask permission or something. need big help. thanks. i've searched some template regarding the enable permission but got to much error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private boolean isLocationPermissionGrandted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private void getLocationPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATTION_CODE);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_LOCATTION_CODE);
        }
    }
```

```
if (isLocationPermissionGrandted())
     initializeWebView();
else
     getLocationPermission();
```