# android webview geolocation tracking when app in the background and phone locked

Tags: android, angular, geolocation, android-webview

I have followed the implementation mentioned in [Grishma Ukani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661081/enable-geolocation-on-webview) post - accepted solution and my app is working fine, but I also want it to work in the background, I have added all the permissions I could think of but still not working..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.access_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND" />
```

if this is not possible, then what can I do to solve this? my app is an `Angular6` web app that tracks a delivery man location every 10 seconds in background and update `Firebase Realtime database`.

I think it is possible because Firefox browser allow GPS activity in the background and every browser actually uses `WebView` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Using WebView outside an Activity context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context)

Comment: When your app is in the background you have to initiate a foreground service in order to continue execution (i.e. all those "App is running in the background" notifications). This means you will not run your WebView in an Activity anymore. Thus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865035/android-using-webview-outside-an-activity-context

Comment: Also - browsers are not forced to use WebView. FireFox actually uses GeckoView - https://www.raywenderlich.com/1381698-android-tutorial-for-geckoview-getting-started