# Android web application: Application does not have sufficient geolocation permissions

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, leaflet, geolocation

I am trying to make an Android App that just shows a map inside a WebView component.

I have started with the [How to Convert a Website into an Android Application using Android Studio](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-convert-a-website-into-an-android-app-from-scratch-de19c84a5801) tutorial and then try to allow the browser to use JavaScript and the position of the device.

To allow the WebView to use the position I have applied the following guides and answers

- [Enable GeoLocation On Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661081/enable-geolocation-on-webview?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [android webview geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation)
- [Enable Geolocation in a WebView (Android)](https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/how-to-enable-geolocation-in-a-webview-android/)

but, when I click on the current position button, I still get the following message:

> Geolocation error: Application does not have sufficient geolocation
> permissions..

[image: Error message screen]

I don't think this is a duplicate question as this is specific about Leafet map JS library and about a specific case.

## What I have tried

At the moment my app is made of the following files:

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.vinaysomawat.careerhigh;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //private WebView mywebview;


    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                                                       //GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                                                       android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback){
            // Always grant permission since the app itself requires location
            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    }



    WebView mywebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();

        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        // Below required for geolocation
        mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        mywebview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mywebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mywebview.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());


        mywebview.loadUrl("https://domoritz.github.io/leaflet-locatecontrol/demo/");

    }





    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
        } else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.action_settings){
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vinaysomawat.careerhigh"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/faviconcircular"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/faviconcircular"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix the geolocation problem? Thank you in advice.

Comment: It doesn't look like you show the android runtime permission dialog. Does your app ask the user at runtime for the Location Permission with a System Dialog? See this for reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime

Comment: It doesn't ask it, but I can't understand why. onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt should show the prompt to the user.

Comment: You have to explicitly do it yourself. Check the SO asnwers again which you have linked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48661518/2258611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your class with your permissions and then call it in onCreate

```
    private fun checkPermissions() {
    val permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this@MainActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this@MainActivity,
            permissions,
            requestExternalStorageCode
        )
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to override permissions callback to check if user granted you permissions:

```
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    if (requestCode == requestExternalStorageCode) {
        if (grantResults.size > 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //to whatever you need after the permission is granted
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` isntead of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: Yes, add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.